# reading keys shell

Tags: json, shell, jq

Now, I have done the following:

```
for row in $(echo "${values}" | jq -r '.[]'); do
    -jq() {
        echo ${row} | jq -r ${1}
    }
    echo $(_jq '.samplekey')
done
```

Here, I am unable to figure out how to extract the keys without passing in the exact keyname. Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**`bash`** + **`jq`** solution:

Assuming your *JSON* data is saved to `data.json` file:

```
IFS=$'\t'; while read -r k v; do 
    export "$k=\"$v\""
done < <(jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv' data.json)
```

Results:

```
$ echo "$HELLO1"
"world1"
 echo "$SAMPLEKEY"
"samplevalue"
```

Comment: 1. I tried using this with a file with request saved in data.json, but when I try to echo on terminal, nothing is printed which means the values aren't getting stored it appears.
2. If instead of a file, I would like to use a simple variable containing the same json, can I do that as well?

Comment: @Qirohchan, I think you've made some mistakes. And here's a screenshot with working fine process https://ibb.co/izZNyb .Check your code again

Comment: you are right. Somehow when I paste this command in a different shell file, and then run the shell file, the results don't come out. That is, the variables are just blank. Also, would you be able to advise on Q2 in the in the first comment as well?

Comment: @Qirohchan, https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=bash+export+variable+from+another+script&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=HJdpWqLMOYbZ8AeWmoLQCQ

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am saying, I have a shell script, that will have the above three commands. But the first line of the script will have the following command: `values=$(./vault read --format=json secret/hello)`. This basically generates the JSON I pasted above. Now that I have the JSON in variable `values`, how do I use it in your command?

Comment: @Qirohchan, here you go: `jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv' <<<"$values"` OR `jq -nr --argjson data "$values" '$data.data | to_entries[] | [(.key|ascii_upcase), .value] | @tsv'`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - It's better to use the idiom: `while IFS=$'\t' read ....` so that the impact is local.

Answer (score 0):

I try to use utility `sed` to extract keys list in **data** section. Here I assume the file name is `/tmp/data.json` which contains the origin json data.

```
sed -r -n '/"data"/,/}/{/[{}]/d;s/^[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)":.*/\U\1/g;p}' /tmp/data.json
```

the output is

```
HELLO1
SAMPLEKEY
```

#### Explanation

1. The delimiter of json data is `"data"` and `}`, just use sed extract the lines list in them;
2. `/[{}]/d` means remove lines which contain punctation `{` or `}`;
3. Set `:` as field delimiter in a line, extract target characters befrom `:`, use `\U` to upper all characters.

#### PS

If you wanna `export` them (export key=val), maybe you could try

```
sed -r -n '/"data"/,/}/{/[{}]/d;s/^[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)":[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)".*$/\1|\2/g;p}' /tmp/data.json | while IFS="|" read -r item val;do item="${item^^}"; item="${val}"; export "${item}"; echo ${item}; done
```

whihin `while` loop.

Comment: so, I need to run the command like `export HELLO1=world1` and `export SAMPLEKEY=samplevalue` . These statements are to be run as part of the shell script, and for each member of the key list.

Comment: when I run the command you pasted, it just says, `sed: illegal option -- r`. Is there a wrong usage being done here?

Comment: @Qirohchan you use MacOS?  try to use `-E` replace `-r`. In `man sed`, it said *-E, -r, --regexp-extended: use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).*

Comment: when I run the command with -E flag, it says, `sed: 1: "/"data"/,/}/{/[{}]/d;s/ ...": extra characters at the end of p command`